# Subsetting a two dimensional tensor with a one dimensional tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to extract from each row of a two-dimensional tensor the column that is stored in another one dimensional tensor.

```
import torch
test_tensor = tensor([1,-2,3], [-2,7,4]).float()
select_tensor = tensor([1,2])
```

So in this particular example I would like to get the element in position 1 for the first row (so -2) and the element in position 2 for the second row (so 4).
I tried:

```
test_tensor[:, select_tensor]
```

But this selects the elements at position 1 and 2 for each row. I suspect it might be something very simple that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather)

```py
import torch
test_tensor = torch.tensor([[1,-2,3], [-2,7,4]]).float()
select_tensor = torch.tensor([1,2], dtype=torch.int64).view(-1,1) # number of dimension should match with the test tensor.
final_tensor = torch.gather(test_tensor, 1, select_tensor)
final_tensor
```

output

```
tensor([[-2.],
        [ 4.]])
```

or, use `torch.view` to flatten the output tensor: `final_tensor.view(-1)` will give you `tensor([-2.,  4.])`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a solution with indexing, you need to index on `axis=0` as well, you could do that with [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.arange.html):

```
>>> test_tensor = torch.tensor([[1,-2,3], [-2,7,4]])
>>> select_tensor = torch.tensor([1,2])

>>> test_tensor[torch.arange(len(select_tensor)), select_tensor]
tensor([-2,  4])
```

Comment: Seems like this solution is from here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/selecting-element-on-dimension-from-list-of-indexes/36319